# XML Parsing Golang

Tags: xml, go

Scenario:
I have an XML structure I'm trying to parse, I don't know how to set up a struct where the value of an xml attribute contains text and more nested values. All other attributes have been set properly, I'm not sure if I'll need to get the value of the source and create a separate parser to retrieve the values of the  elements.

```
<trans-unit id="some.message">
    <source>hello %<ph id="first_name">{0}</ph> %<ph id="last_name">{1}</ph>
    </source>
    <target/>
</trans-unit>

type TransUnit struct {
  Id string `xml:"id,attr"`
  Source string `xml:"source"`
  SourceVars MixedVars `xml:"source>ph"`
  Target string `xml:"target"`
}

type MixedVars []MixedVar

type MixedVar struct {
  VarName string `xml:"id,attr"`
}
```

**EDIT:** 
I'm trying to parse the source into a string that follows the form:
hello %{first_name} %{last_name}

Unmarshalling the xml string with the current structs returns a an empty struct

@plato using innerxml sets the source to:

```
<source>Are you sure you want to reset the reservation for %<ph id="first_name">{0}</ph> %<ph id="last_name">{1}</ph>
```

This puts me in a similar situation where I still have nested xml tags interpolated within the source value

Comment: I think you can implement your own Unmarshal method on MixedVars but i'm not sure. Also check this out, from the soruce of encoding/xml: *If the struct has a field of type []byte or string with tag ",innerxml", Unmarshal accumulates the raw XML nested inside the element in that field.* Might help

Comment: @plato I've tried using innerxml but I'm still running into a similar situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to unmarshal the source xml node into both the raw xml and a slice of variables at once, eg:

```
type TransUnit struct {
    ID     string `xml:"id,attr"`
    Source Source `xml:"source"`
    Target string `xml:"target"`
}

type Source struct {
    Raw  string `xml:",innerxml"`
    Text string `xml:",chardata"`
    Vars []Var  `xml:"ph"`
}

type Var struct {
    ID    string `xml:"id,attr"`
    Value string `xml:",innerxml"`
}
```

See a [running example](https://play.golang.org/p/7I1bxgxCCO). You should be good to go from there.